# How to restrict rows from SSIS Data Source?

Tags: ssis, oledb, datasource

I have an OLE DB Data Source in an SSIS package. I want to restrict rows to return data from a specific date (it has a date column). How can this be achieved in SSIS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I changed the "Data Access Mode" property of the "OLE DB Source" component to "SQL Command" and specified a where clause in the TSQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [conditional split](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/conditional-split-transformation-in-ssis-2008-uses-and-examples/) control or a script task.

Comment: Will conditional split get all the data from the source and then split it?

Comment: What I basically want is to get only selected rows from the source as the source data weighs a ton